# Calculating O(n) for a hasmap vs binary search

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, complexity-theory, binary-search, computation-theory

I'm trying to clarify how to calculate O(n) for the following case:

Given a sorted array, how would you find two numbers whose sum is equal to a given number x in O(n)?

An O(n) solution would be:

1. Remove the first element of the array (e0)
2. Add this to a hashmap
3. Remove the first element of the array (e1)
4. Target is the difference between e1 and x
5. If the target exists in the hash map return the pair
6. Add e1 to the hashmap
7. Repeat steps 3-6 until you find a pair or run out of elements

This would be worst case O(n) as you only need a single pass on the array.

An O(n * log n) solution would be:

1. Remove the first element from the array (e1)
2. Target is the difference between the first element and x
3. Binary search the rest of the array for the target
4. If it exists return the pair
5. Repeat steps 1–4 till you find a pair or run out of elements

This is O(n log n) as you would need to run a binary search (log n) at worst n/2 times giving O(n/2 * log n) which in big O is O(n * log n)

Is this correct?

Comment: Removing an element from an array may be O(N), depending on what language/library you use, so it's probably better to just leave the elements in the array otherwise your running time will be multiplied by O(N).

Comment: Ya, a pointer would definitely be better, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, for both algorithm ur analysis is correct.

Your first algorithm uses O(n) space also, coz of hashmap. U can avoid that.

```
Algo : 
1. Consider begin = 0, and end = last_index
2. Consider data[begin] and data[end]
3. If data[begin] + data[end] > req_sum:
        end=end - 1  // u need to decrease ur total sum
   elif data[begin] + data[end] < req_sum:
        begin = begin + 1  // u need to increase ur total sum
   elif data[begin] + data[end] == req_sum:
          print("found")
4. Continue from Step 2.
```

Obviously avoid case where `end < begin` and other corner cases .

Comment: I am just suggesting him other algo for the problem. His hw is to proof time complexity for algos mentioned in question,which I didn't . :)

Comment: Actually I'm a self taugh programmer so this is more for interest. Been doing some competitive programming as well as algo optimisation so I'm trying to wrap my head around time complexity by reading Wikipedia and watching YouTube. It's great to get some feedback because I have no answer sheet :-)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework assignment problem in some course you're taking. I won't solve it for you - although it is easy enough to find the solution online - but I will tell you that I am 99% certain that your solution must take O(n) time as the **worst-case complexity**. Hash-based solutions only take O(1) time per lookup **on the average**.